# Want help with debugging a For-loop

Tags: scoping, debugging, procedural-programming

I'm trying to run a simulation, which at the end gives a value 'qber'. Now I want to run this simulation multiple times with different values of 'p' each time. And these value of 'p' are actually the elements of a list already defined before. 
My code is as follows:

```
x := RandomChoice[{0, π}];
y := RandomChoice[{0, π/2, π, 3 π/2}];
prob = {0.25, 0.05}
f2[{result_, plist_}] := 
   With[{k = RandomReal[]}, 
     Which[
       k < 0.7, {0, plist}, 
       (k > 0.7) && (k < 0.7 + plist[[1]]), 
         {π/10, If[plist[[1]] == prob[[2]], plist, Reverse @ plist]},
       True, {-π/10, If[plist[[1]] == prob[[1]], plist, Reverse @ plist]}]]
 mylist = #[[1]] & /@ NestList[f2, {0, prob}, 9]
 e = Accumulate[mylist]
```

> ```
> {0.15, 0.15} 
> {0, 0, 0, -(π/10), π/10, 0, -(π/10), 0, 0, -(π/10)}
> {0, 0, 0, -(π/10), π/10, 0, -(π/10), 0, 0, -(π/10)}
> ```

Then the last list in the above output is used for the values of `p`, in the following for-loop:

```
For[i = 1; i <= 10, i++, 
  p = e[[i]]; 
  Module[{}, 
    dat3 = Table[x - y + p, 100];
    dat34 := Mod[dat3, 2 π];
    dat334 := Transpose[{dat3, dat34}];
    ph0 := Select[dat334, #[[1]] == 0 &];
    ph1 := Select[dat334, #[[1]] == π || #[[1]] == -π &];
    ph2 := 
      Select[dat334, 
        #[[1]] == π/2 || #[[1]] == -π/2  || #[[1]] == 3 π/2 || #[[1]] == -3 π/2 &];
    dats := ph0[[All, 2]];
    datt := ph1[[All, 2]];
    datu := ph2[[All, 2]];
    datscos := N[(Cos[(dats)/2])^2];
    dattcos := N[(Cos[(datt)/2])^2];
    datucos := N[(Cos[(datu)/2])^2];
    det1ss := Length[datscos]; 
    det1tt := Length[dattcos];
    det1uu := Length[datucos];
    rr := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
    For[j = 1; det1s = 0, j <= det1ss, j++, 
      If[rr <= datscos[[j]], det1s = det1s + 1];];
    For[k = 1; det1t = 0, k <= det1tt, k++, 
      If[rr <= dattcos[[k]], det1t = det1t + 1];];
    For[l = 1; det1u = 0, l <= det1uu, l++, 
      If[rr <= datucos[[l]], det1u = det1u + 1];];
    det2s := det1ss - det1s;
    det2t := det1tt - det1t;
    det2u := det1uu - det1u;
    aa := {det1s, det2s};
    bb := {det1t, det2t};
    cc := {det1u, det2u};
    det1 := {{1, det1s}, {3, det1t}, {5, det1u}};
    det2 := {{1.5, det2s}, {3.5, det2t}, {5.5, det2u}};
    qber = N[((det2s/(det1s + det2s)) + (det1t/(det1t + det2t)))/2];];
    Print[qber]]
```

Now when I try to run it, it doesn't give any output. And when I keep the print command outside the for loop(just to check), it says `Indeterminate`. But I don't think the value of `qber` can come out to be `Indeterminant` in anyway. However, I'm unable to find any bug in the code. If you can, then please help me out.

P.S.: I also tried to run the for-loop without using `Module`, and directly putting all the values inside the for-loop. But still it gives the same error.

Comment: Look up the syntax of `For`. You use semicoli where commata are in order. Even better: use `Do`. Btw: Mathematica is neither Pascal nor Maple. An simple assignment is done with `=`, not with `:=`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have used  `:=` for delayed assignment. And that gives different random values everytime I call it, and that's what I need. Also, I have used semicolon, because there are inside a module. And yes, I agree that at some places, delayed assignment wasn't required, still I used it. My bad!

Comment: Does it work, if you fix the `For` loop? Additionally, when you use `Module` with no local variables, you don't need it. It has no effect other than lengthening your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the semicolon/comma thing and put the print statement inside the module but you have some situations where you are dividing by zero causing qber to be indeterminate.  This happens when det1s = -det2s or when det1t = -det2t.  Adding an if statement to qber prevents dividing by zero.

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
 p = e[[i]];
 Module[{}, dat3 = Table[x - y + p, 100];
  dat34 := Mod[dat3, 2 \[Pi]];
  dat334 := Transpose[{dat3, dat34}];
  ph0 := Select[dat334, #[[1]] == 0 &];
  ph1 := Select[dat334, #[[1]] == \[Pi] || #[[1]] == -\[Pi] &];
  ph2 := Select[
    dat334, #[[1]] == \[Pi]/2 || #[[1]] == -\[Pi]/2 || #[[1]] == 
       3 \[Pi]/2 || #[[1]] == -3 \[Pi]/2 &];
  dats := ph0[[All, 2]];
  datt := ph1[[All, 2]];
  datu := ph2[[All, 2]];
  datscos := N[(Cos[(dats)/2])^2];
  dattcos := N[(Cos[(datt)/2])^2];
  datucos := N[(Cos[(datu)/2])^2];
  det1ss := Length[datscos];
  det1tt := Length[dattcos];
  det1uu := Length[datucos];
  rr := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
  For[j = 1; det1s = 0, j <= det1ss, j++, 
   If[rr <= datscos[[j]], det1s = det1s + 1];];
  For[k = 1; det1t = 0, k <= det1tt, k++, 
   If[rr <= dattcos[[k]], det1t = det1t + 1];];
  For[l = 1; det1u = 0, l <= det1uu, l++, 
   If[rr <= datucos[[l]], det1u = det1u + 1];];
  det2s := det1ss - det1s;
  det2t := det1tt - det1t;
  det2u := det1uu - det1u;
  aa := {det1s, det2s};
  bb := {det1t, det2t};
  cc := {det1u, det2u};
  det1 := {{1, det1s}, {3, det1t}, {5, det1u}};
  det2 := {{1.5, det2s}, {3.5, det2t}, {5.5, det2u}};
 (* If[det1s + det2s != 0 && det1t + det2t != 0,
   qber = N[((det2s/(det1s + det2s)) + (det1t/(det1t + det2t)))/2];
   Print[qber]];*)
  othervals := {det1sval -> det1s, det2sval -> det2s, det1tval -> det1t,
    det2tval -> det2t};
  If[det1s + det2s != 0 && det1t + det2t != 0, 
    qber = N[((det2s/(det1s + det2s)) + (det1t/(det1t + det2t)))/2];
   Print[{qberval -> qber, othervals}], 
   Print[{qberval -> Undefined, othervals}]]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. And it gives output for only 2-3 out of 10. But I wonder how's that possible! Because as you can see from those for-loops, they start from 0, and there's no way that anyone of them can go negative. And one more thing I noticed just now is that, output is indeterminate for only non-zero values of 'p'.

Comment: You can have it print out some values to help debugging see last two lines of edited answer.

Comment: Sometimes det1s, det2s det1t and det2t are zero.